# jit - "Failed in nopython mode pipeline" error, despite not using nopython in numba

Tags: python, scipy, dynamic-programming, numba, jit

I am using value function iteration to solve a complex dynamic programming problem with many states. I want to use numba/jit to speed up my code (and eventually parallelize the for loops). When I use the `@jit` decorator in my code, I am getting a `nopython` error despite me not invoking `nopython` mode.

```
@jit
def vfi(cm, λ=1):
    vf_new = np.zeros_like(cm.vf)
    k_prime = np.zeros_like(cm.k_opt)
    for k_i in range(cm.k_grid_size):
        cm.set_k(cm.kgrid[k_i])
        for b_i in range(cm.cb_grid_size):
            cm.set_b(cm.cb_mesh[0][b_i])
            for s_i in range(2):
                cm.set_s(s_i)
                b_prime = cm.b_prime(cm.kgrid)
                vf_interp = RegularGridInterpolator((cm.kgrid, cm.cb_mesh[0],cm.sgrid), cm.vf)
                objective = cm.F - cm.T(cm.kgrid) - cm.C(cm.kgrid) + cm.β*cm.p*np.array([vf_interp(x) for x in zip(cm.kgrid,b_prime,np.zeros_like(b_prime))]) + cm.β*(1-cm.p)*np.array([vf_interp(x) for x in zip(cm.kgrid,b_prime,np.ones_like(b_prime))])
                vf_new[k_i,b_i,s_i] = np.max(objective)
                k_prime[k_i,b_i,s_i] = np.argmax(objective)
    error = np.max(np.abs(cm.vf - vf_new))
    cm.vf = cm.vf + λ*(vf_new-cm.vf)
    cm.k_opt = k_prime
    return error        

qe.util.tic()
cm = CarrybacksModel()
error = 10000000
itern=0
tol = 1e-5
while error>tol:
    error = vfi(cm)
    itern+=1
    print(f"Iteration number {itern}, error = {error}.")
print(f"Completed in {itern} iterations.")
qe.util.toc()
```

Returns the following error:

```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[57], line 7
      5 tol = 1e-5
      6 while error>tol:
----> 7     error = vfi(cm)
      8     itern+=1
      9     print(f"Iteration number {itern}, error = {error}.")

File ~\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py:468, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    464         msg = (f"{str(e).rstrip()} \n\nThis error may have been caused "
    465                f"by the following argument(s):\n{args_str}\n")
    466         e.patch_message(msg)
--> 468     error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    469 except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    470     # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info
    471     error_rewrite(e, 'unsupported_error')

File ~\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py:409, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args.<locals>.error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    407     raise e
    408 else:
--> 409     raise e.with_traceback(None)

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'RegularGridInterpolator': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'type'>

File "..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16688\910653365.py", line 12:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
 

This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 0: Cannot determine Numba type of <class '__main__.CarrybacksModel'>
```

I am aware that I cannot use njit/nopython mode since I am defining my own class and scipy's `RegularGridInterpolator` doesn't seem to be compatible. However, I thought that by using the `@jit` decorator instead of `@njit` then `nopython` should never be invoked. Why am I receiving a `nopython` error?

I am open to using a different function instead of `RegularGridInterpolator` if necessary - I coded one up myself and decorated that with `@jit` but still received the same error.

Comment: Note that Numba as nearly no benefit here. It can only speed up loops but loops should clearly not be the bottleneck in this code. In objmode, Numpy calls/accesses are not optimized. In fact, what makes Numba fast is knowing the types of all variables and using native ones. If one variable is an object, then Numba cannot generate native assembly code and fallback to the slow pure-Python mode with slightly faster loops. In such a case, Cython is more useful since you can at least specify types for a part of the objects so to speed up partially the computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think nopython mode is the default.

From [decorators.py in the numba github repo](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/main/numba/core/decorators.py):

```py
    if nopython is False:
        msg = ("The keyword argument 'nopython=False' was supplied. From "
               "Numba 0.59.0 the default is True and supplying this argument "
               "has no effect.")
```

I think the option you are looking for to force the python mode is called `forceobj`.

Comment: This is right, using forceobj fixed the issue! Thank you